# PHP RegEx - match to the end of a string

Tags: php, regex

If my string is

```
Size : 93743 bytes Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms): 00:00:00.156
```

How do I match the value that appears after the `(hh:mm:ss.ms):` ?

```
00:00:00.156
```

I know how to match if there are more characters following the value, but there aren't any more characters after it and I do not want to include the size information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like so:

```
<?php
$text = "Size : 93743 bytes Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms): 00:00:00.156";

# match literal '(' followed by 'hh:mm:ss.ms' followed by literal ')'
# then ':' then zero or more whitespace characters ('\s')
# then, capture one or more characters in the group 0-9, '.', and ':'
# finally, eat zero or more whitespace characters and an end of line ('$')
if (preg_match('/\(hh:mm:ss.ms\):\s*([0-9.:]+)\s*$/', $text, $matches)) {
    echo "captured: {$matches[1]}\n";
}
?>
```

This gives:

```
captured: 00:00:00.156
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` anchors the regex to the end of the string:

```
<?php
$str = "Size : 93743 bytes Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms): 00:00:00.156";

$matches = array();

if (preg_match('/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d$/', $str, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

#### Output:

```
string(12) "00:00:00.156"
```

Comment: how about `00:00:00:1` or `00:00:00:22`?

Comment: @Amarghosh Question didn't indicate that either of those are possible inputs; I assume the format would be `...00:100` and `...00:220` in those cases.

Comment: This still isn't working, not sure if there is some kind of extra space after the string or what... and yes, the format would be `...00:100` - is that to say `$` tells the `preg_match` that it should stop looking at that point, or to continue looking until the end of the string? I think I need something that says to stop the match after the last `\d`